# How to access kubernete pods on my development environment?

Tags: kubernetes, gcloud, google-kubernetes-engine

right now i'm accessing my pods (postgres port 5432) trough a service that is  exposed, but since **gcloud** charge for every forwarding rule created, the amount of pods i need to monitor or to execute stuff in it, is costing me more and more, is there a way to create a single expose service for all of my pods? or can i create some sort of `vpn`? `putty tunnel` or something? any help would be appreciated!
I'm also using 
kubectl exec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a managed solution then Google is offering VPN for that:
https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/vpn/

If you are happy to roll your own then you can create a new Compute instance on the same network where your nodes are and set up openvpn there. This will give you a fix ip as a freebie.

A more advanced solution is if you run openvpn as a pod (or pods) and use a Service with NodePort to expose it. (Optionally manually create a single loadbalacer on google cloud to get a static ip for that.)

At the end of the day the ideal solution depends much on your environment and goal.

Comment: yeah im gonna research the  vpn option on google or create my own vpn, i was thinking on a pod that controls the routes and tunnel with ssh in to it, but vpn is a more simpler and easier option, thanks!

Comment: If you go with the pod solution you will want to look into the hostNetwork option in the pod spec